# my application's gem has dependency with different-2 version of i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

My rails application's gems are dependent on 2 different versions of i18n: 0.6.1 and 0.6.4. Currently I have my Gemfile locked with version 0.6.4. When I run my rails app via `bundle exec`, the app ask for version 0.6.1 as well and the app server won't start.

Should I remove one of the versions of i18n and it's all dependencies, or there is any other alternative so I don't  have to remove any of i18n versions?

Note: I am not using rvm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the exact error message?

Comment: opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated i18n 0.6.1, but your Gemfile requires i18n 0.6.4. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: After uninstalling 0.6.1, I am getting following issue:`to_specs': Could not find i18n (= 0.6.1) amongst [RedCloth-4.2.9, actionmailer-3.2.13, actionmailer-3.2.11, actionpack-3.2.13, actionpack-3.2.11, active_utils-2.0.0, active_utils-1.0.5, activeadmin-0.6.0, activemerchant-1.35.1, activemerchant-1.33.0, activemodel-3.2.13, activemodel-3.2.11, activerecord-3.2.13, activerecord-3.2.11, activeresource-3.2.13, activeresource-3.2.11, activesupport-3.2.13, activesupport-3.2.11, ansi-1.4.3, arbre-1.0.1, arel-3.0.2, atomic-1.1.10, aws-sdk-1.8.3.1] (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Do you found some solution?